# async/await func returning a promise instead of data

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I have the following function in JS which is supposed to read all the entries in a firebase database.

```
async function getMarket() {

let marketRef = db.ref('/market');
let snapshot = await marketRef.once('value');
return snapshot.val();

}
```

For some reason when I call this function it returns `Promise { <state>: "pending" }`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Async functions have to return `Promise` because they can't return concrete results immediately - that's a core premise of asynchronous computation.

Comment: It sounds like the value of your snapshot is a promise, you'll have to await that as well

Comment: @SterlingArcher `async` functions always return promises, regardless of what's returned within them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `async` function returns a `Promise`. Chain `.then()` and `.catch()` to process the returned `Promise` value

Comment: This is using `async/await` syntax, no need to use `then` when you await a promise, usually

Comment: @SterlingArcher OP describes calling the function. OP appears to expect a value that is not a `Promise` to be returned from the function. `.then()` and needs to be chained to process the  `Promise` value returned from the function

Comment: Right, which would be fine if it wasn't a promise, but with async await you don't need to use `then` to extract the value (an example from my game https://github.com/RUJodan/Source-React/blob/master/routes/login.js)

Comment: @SterlingArcher You _do_ need `.then` (or another `async` function) if you want to extract the value _returned_ from an `async` function. That is what OP is asking about. In the file you linked to, all of the functions are `async`.

Comment: Right, that's why I should they might have to await the results as well. `then` isn't required when using the async wait syntax is what I'm trying to say. Like in a node server when you make an XHR, you have to `await response.json()` to get the actual json results. We're both on the same page here, just syntactical differences

Comment: @SterlingArcher Have you read the actual question: _"
For some reason when I call this function it returns `Promise { <state>: "pending" }`. Why is this happening?"_ ?